# the app cannot read from the SQLite database i created after i wrote in the database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-view

hey guys this is a contacts app where the user enters the contacts by himself and can edit on him later...i actually redid many parts inside this app but everytime i try to display the contacts i get the below error in the logcat which terminates my app

```
01-05 21:04:16.138: E/CursorWindow(16448): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 16 rows, 4 columns.
```

please help, i put the main and the DB and the view classes below

Main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button add, choose, display;
TextView contactsdisplay;
DBgenerator db;// Instantiate the database to be used by this method//

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
    choose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choosebutton);
    display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.displaybutton);
    contactsdisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactsdisplay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent j = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Manipulator.class);
            startActivity(j);
        }
    });
    choose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent k = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayEdit.class);
            startActivity(k);
        }
    });
    display.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent f = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayContacts.class);
            startActivity(f);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

DB class:

```
public class DBgenerator {
public static final String Key_ROWID = "_id";// the row id//
public static final String Key_FirstName = "Person_firstname";
public static final String Key_LastName = "Person_lastname";
public static final String Key_Mobile = "Mobile";
public static final String Key_Address = "Address";

private static final String Database_name = "contacts";
private static final String Database_table = "contactstable";
private static final int Database_version = 1;
// create database//
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = " CREATE TABLE "
        + Database_table + "(" + Key_ROWID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Key_FirstName
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Key_LastName + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + Key_Mobile + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Key_Address
        + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

private dbmanipulation manipulate;// make an instance of the inner class to
                                    // be frequently used//
private Context mycontext;
private SQLiteDatabase mydb;

private static class dbmanipulation extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public dbmanipulation(Context context) {
        super(context, Database_name, null, Database_version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // CREATE AND EXECUTE YOUR DATABASE
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Database_table);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DBgenerator(Context c) {
    /*
     * i am not sure why he did this one but i am sure that this is used to
     * take in the context of which activity will be using the database
     * which was probably one of the things i was missing in the SQLite
     */
    mycontext = c;

}

public DBgenerator open() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    manipulate = new dbmanipulation(mycontext);
    mydb = manipulate.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    manipulate.close();
}

public long addnewcontact(String firstName, String lastName,
        String mobileno, String contactAddress) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Key_FirstName, firstName);
    cv.put(Key_LastName, lastName);
    cv.put(Key_Mobile, mobileno);
    cv.put(Key_Address, contactAddress);
    return mydb.insert(Database_table, null, cv);
}

public String getallcontacts() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] Columns = new String[] { Key_FirstName, Key_LastName,
            Key_Mobile, Key_Address };
    Cursor c = mydb.query(Database_table, Columns, null, null, null, null,
            null);
    // we need to select and search for the users by thier IDs//
    int contactrow = c.getColumnIndex(Key_ROWID);
    int contactfname = c.getColumnIndex(Key_FirstName);
    int contactlname = c.getColumnIndex(Key_LastName);
    int contactmobile = c.getColumnIndex(Key_Mobile);
    int contactaddress = c.getColumnIndex(Key_Address);
    // loop inside the DB starting by the first row//
    String returnedcontacts = "";

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())// start from the
                                                            // beginning...not
                                                            // at the
                                                            // end..increment//
    {
        returnedcontacts = returnedcontacts + c.getString(contactrow) + " "
                + c.getString(contactfname) + " "
                + c.getString(contactlname) + " "
                + c.getString(contactmobile) + " "
                + c.getString(contactaddress) + " " + "\n";

    }

    return returnedcontacts;
}

}
```

the view class:

```
public class DisplayContacts extends Activity {
TextView contacts;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewcontacts);
    contacts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactviewdata);
    // display the contacts//
    displaycontacts();

}

private void displaycontacts() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBgenerator view = new DBgenerator(DisplayContacts.this);
    view.open();
    String ContactsData = view.getallcontacts();
    view.close();
    contacts.setText(ContactsData);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

please help , thx guys

P.S. below is my LOGCAT

```
01-05 21:04:00.903: E/Trace(16448): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-05 21:04:01.138: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:01.221: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:02.218: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x4f06b390] frames:2, duration:1.042000, fps:1.918633
01-05 21:04:02.225: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:02.492: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:02.578: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:02.619: W/MMUMapper(16448): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x526dd000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-05 21:04:02.620: W/MMUMapper(16448): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52993000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-05 21:04:02.621: W/MMUMapper(16448): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52b3b000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-05 21:04:03.033: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:03.657: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:4, duration:1.089000, fps:3.671077
01-05 21:04:04.768: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:3, duration:1.111000, fps:2.698411
01-05 21:04:05.844: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:4, duration:1.084000, fps:3.687304
01-05 21:04:07.112: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:4, duration:1.273000, fps:3.140990
01-05 21:04:08.240: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:3, duration:1.125000, fps:2.665755
01-05 21:04:09.600: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:5, duration:1.362000, fps:3.668667
01-05 21:04:10.667: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:5, duration:1.065000, fps:4.691889
01-05 21:04:11.673: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:4, duration:1.007000, fps:3.969711
01-05 21:04:13.133: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:7, duration:1.459000, fps:4.795339
01-05 21:04:14.171: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x528c8ab0] frames:9, duration:1.037000, fps:8.675249
01-05 21:04:14.797: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:14.821: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:14.867: W/MMUMapper(16448): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52bd1000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-05 21:04:14.868: W/MMUMapper(16448): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x52c67000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-05 21:04:14.868: W/MMUMapper(16448): invalid operation for unregister MVA with VA(0x526a7000) size(614400) f(0x5)
01-05 21:04:15.964: I/SurfaceTextureClient(16448): [0x5276e3d0] frames:2, duration:1.156000, fps:1.729373
01-05 21:04:15.968: W/MMUMapper(16448): fail to register MVA, unsupported format(0x5)
01-05 21:04:16.138: E/CursorWindow(16448): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 16 rows, 4 columns.
01-05 21:04:16.141: W/dalvikvm(16448): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419ff908)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hossa.sqliteexample/com.hossa.sqliteexample.DisplayContacts}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2203)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1301)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5006)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at com.hossa.sqliteexample.DBgenerator.getallcontacts(DBgenerator.java:97)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at com.hossa.sqliteexample.DisplayContacts.displaycontacts(DisplayContacts.java:23)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at com.hossa.sqliteexample.DisplayContacts.onCreate(DisplayContacts.java:16)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5076)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2167)
01-05 21:04:16.154: E/AndroidRuntime(16448):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your getAllContacts you try to access the _id ("Key_ROWID") column through the cursor, which is not included in the column list ("Columns") of the query. Column cannot be found, index returned ("contactrow") is -1, access throws exception. Add Key_ROWID to Columns and see if that works.

Btw, instead of `for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())` you can simply write `while( c.moveToNext() )`.

P.S.: The docs for [getColumnIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex%28java.lang.String%29) give a useful recommendation which I absolutely second:

> If you expect the column to exist use [getColumnIndexOrThrow(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndexOrThrow%28java.lang.String%29) instead, which will make the error more clear.

So whenever you're in control of the columns you `select` use the latter. (The opposite could be a `select * from ...` or a query on a table your application does not control or that may be of another version. "ContactsContract" anyone?)

Comment: you are right my friend, i just found out that this was the problem...this is embarrassing :( but i had a long day and i am so sleepy...still thank you Hanno :)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the problem is in that piece of code:

.. `c.getString(contactfname)` ...

I am afraid `contactfname` is not the correct column index. Try to `Log` your query, and display each result. For example, the first thing I would try, would be to check the column indices (contactfname, contactlname ...) using `Log`. Since the error is indicating that you are trying to get the string from wrong column index (it should not be -1). You can also try manually giving indexes.